# linked list using smart pointers - where is it going wrong?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstddef>
#include<string>

using namespace std;
class spexception
{
    protected:  
    string description;
    public:
    spexception();
    spexception(const string&);
    virtual const string& what();
};

template <class T>
class sp
{
    private:
    T* p;
    sp(T*);
    public:
    sp();
    sp(const T&);
    sp(int);
    T& operator * ();
    T* operator -> ();
    sp& operator = (const sp&);
    sp& operator = (const T&);
    sp& operator = (int);
    bool operator == (const sp&);
    ~sp();
};

spexception::spexception() : description("No description.")
{}

spexception::spexception(const string& s) : description(s)
{}

const string& spexception::what()
{
    return description;
}

template<class T>
sp<T>::sp()
{
    p = NULL;
}

template<class T>
sp<T>::~sp()
{
    if(p!=NULL) delete p;
}

template<class T>
sp<T>::sp(const T& t)
{
    p = new T(t);
}

template<class T>
sp<T>::sp(int i)
{
    if(i!=0) throw spexception("Smart pointer cannot be initialized from a non-zero integer.");
    p = NULL;
}

template<class T>
sp<T>& sp<T>::operator = (const sp& q)
{
    if(*this==q) return *this;
    if(p!=NULL) delete p;
    p = q.p;
    return *this;
}

template<class T>
sp<T>& sp<T>::operator = (const T& t)
{
    p = new T(t);
}

template<class T>
sp<T>& sp<T>::operator = (int i)
{
    if(i!=0) throw spexception();
    p = NULL;
}

template<class T>
bool sp<T>::operator == (const sp& q)
{
    return(p==q.p);
}

template<class T>
T& sp<T>::operator * ()
{
    return *p;
}

template<class T>
T* sp<T>::operator -> ()
{
    return p;
}

using namespace std;
class node
{
    public:
    int val;
    sp<node> next;
    node()
    {
        val = 5;
    }
    node(int v) : val(v)
    {
        cout<<"\nNode with value "<<val<<" created.\n";
    }
    ~node()
    {
        cout<<"\nNode with value "<<val<<"destroyed.\n";
    }
};
class list
{
    sp<node> first;
    sp<node> last;
    public:
    list()
    {
        first = NULL;
        last = NULL;
    }
    void add(int v)
    {
        if(last==NULL)
        {
            last = node(v);
            first = last;
            //last->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            last->next = node(v);
            //last->next->next = NULL;
            last = last->next;
        }
    }
};


main()
{
    list l;
    l.add(10);
    l.add(20);
    l.add(30);
    l.add(40);
}
```

The output is "Node with value 40 destroyed" printed infinite times. According to gdb debugger, the problem happens in the list destructor. According to the gd debugger, there is some node which has a smart pointer pointing to the same node. So when the destructor is called it is supposedly being called infinite times. But I dont see this happening in the code. What exactly is the problem?

EDIT: As molbdnilo pointed out, when the destructor for the 'last'smart pointer is called, an attempt is made to delete a dangling pointer. This should cause a crash. However the program is going into an infinite loop instead. Is this a bug with mingw compiler?

Comment: As a sidenote: `if(p!=NULL) delete p;` is equivalent to `delete p;`

Comment: Looks like a classic ownership issue. You have two pointers to the last node; `last` in the list, and the `next` node of its previous node. The node is deallocated when the `next` node is destroyed, so the destruction of `last` is undefined.  Linked lists aren't really a good application for smart pointers,

Comment: The assignment operator of your `sp` class copies the pointer. Since `sp`  deletes the owned pointer, this caues all pointers that were assigned from to be deleted twice.

Comment: the question is why is the node destructor executed infinite times?

Comment: @AbhijitS possibly because you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding `template`s until you've debugged it. `template`s are notorious for giving whacky error messages, even for the simplest of errors.

Comment: can undefined behaviour really cause such weird things to happen? I want to know why?

Comment: @AbhijitS Yes, with UB anything can happen. You should use a memory debugger and see if there's something wrong. Also, why are you using `sp` instead of standard smart pointers?

Comment: @AbhijitS, sry to say but ur code is very very bad

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class T>

        sp<T>& sp<T>::operator = (const sp& q)
        {
            if(*this==q) return *this;
            if(p!=NULL) delete p;
            p = q.p;
            return *this;
        }
```

In the Above Function The Pointer 'p' gets deleted and next instruction tries to assign a value 'q.p' to the deleted 'p',which can cause problem.

I made changes to above function as given below.

```
template<class T>
sp<T>& sp<T>::operator = (const sp& q)
{
    if(*this==q) return *this;
    if(p!=NULL) p = q.p;
    return *this;
}
```

This worked out well.

Comment: this can cause memory leak if p was already pointing to some location on the heap and it was reassigned without first deleting it.

Comment: I have tested the code with valgrind for memory leakage and it didn't show any.In some cases it might.

Answer (score 0):

You have no copy constructor, so the default copy constructor will just copy the pointer, giving you two smart pointer objects that point at the same object.

Similarly, you assignment operator just copies the pointer, giving you two smart pointer objects that point at the same object.

Whenever either of these happens, the destructor for the first smart pointer will delete the object, leaving the other smart pointer dangling.  When the second smart pointer is destroyed, it deletes the already deleted pointer again, causing undefined behavior.

When you copy or assign a smart pointer, you need to either also clone the pointed at object, or have a reference count somewhere that tracks how many pointers point at the same object.  In this latter case, you only delete the object when the refcount drops to 0.